# Show Text on Image Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have an image description shown when hovering over the image which is placed in a div (`#web01`).

I've been toying with the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` and have been able to get text shown but when I link it to a div it doesn't seem to work.

It's probably dead easy but i can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#web01").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#titel").html('<p class="titel">description</p>');
    });
    $("#web01").mouseleave(function () {
        $("#titel").html('<p class="titel"></p>');
    });
})
```

Comment: Try to reproduce it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ then share the link with us.

Comment: Can you not just give the image a title attribute?

Comment: I think a `title` would do it, if you are not in need of anything fancy.

Comment: As @Xotic750 said, why not give just a `title` to the `img` ? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5f64D/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to name your element `title1` and not `titel1` (spelled incorrectly), simply changing the id to `title1` fixes the problem. I've given a working example below.

## [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4zfBy/9/)

Comment: But if the id name of his/hers div is "titel", your comment will render as absolute nonsense.

Comment: @Daniel The fact that all of his javascript works correctly (tested myself) it is a safe assumption that he misspelled `title`. Both events are firing perfectly, so the fact that the text isn't changing tells me that no element is being selected.

Comment: i spelled it like that on purpose, and it still isn't working.

i'll update with the full code in a minute

Comment: @user1379378 Thanks for the update. As Daniel mentioned my answer is then useless

Comment: For all i care "titel" is a legitimate word in a language other than English, so your "safe" assumption is a wild guess in my book. It still is a tip worthwhile though :-) Your show at least that there is basically nothing wrong with the code in the question.

Comment: @Daniel You're correct, it was a guess that I *thought* would work ;)

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="web01" title="myTitle">...</div>` or `<img src="..." title="myTitle"/>` will show the native browser title (tooltip).

Answer (score 0):

In the example on http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ I saw them use **this** in the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#web01").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#titel",this).html('description'); 
 });

 $("#web01").mouseleave(function() { 
  $("#titel",this).html(''); 
 });
});
```